# HTTP/3 : frame analysis

Tags: frame, http3

I got a HTTP/3 frame 0x 00 40 78 5f 82.

According to the https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-quic-http-27#page-28

the frame layout should be 32 bit(type), 32 bit(length field), 32 bit(payload).

I don't think the frame has 96 bits.

What do I misunderstand?

I want to find the frame type, length field and length of the payload.

How do I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to page 28:

> Type:  A variable-length integer that identifies the frame type.

> Length:  A variable-length integer that describes the length in bytes
> of the Frame Payload.

> Frame Payload:  A payload, the semantics of which are determined by
> the Type field.

According to the standard the Length field contains the length of the Payload field. The length and the type fields are each a [variable length integer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-quic-transport-27#section-16) of at least 8 and up 64 bits, where the first two bits determine the length of th field. due to this the payload length can be up to 2^62 bytes. The minimum is therefor 1byte+1byte (2 in your case, since the first two bits are 01)+payload (2 in your case).